# Rails4 and Paperclip 4.0.2 callback turns as infinite loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, infinite-loop

I set paperclip to My "Document" model, with a fairly standard config. It works well, but I want to separate the addtitional styles file generation inside a background job (using Resque).

(I would like to stop the creation of the :orginal style to to assign a file manually, but it doesn't seem to be possible)

So, to extract styles inside a background job, I first stop paperclip styles processors.
Then I call the reprocess! inside an after_save callback to generate them.

Doing this put the update action inside an infinite loop, and it is exactly when I call the reprocess!

Here is my Document model (simplified for understanding purpose)

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :attachment

   before_post_process :stop_process
   after_save :process_styles #same result with after_update (since user can only add attachment when updating profile)

   # Kill all paperclip styles
   #still generate the :orginal style. Block that too to copy it manually from remote folder would be nice 
   def stop_process
     false
   end

  #call for the generation of the additional styles (:medium, :thumb) 
  def process_styles
    Profile.processDocumentJob(id)
  end

  #will be a background job
  def self.processDocumentJob(id)
    document = Document.find(id)
    document.attachment.reprocess!
    document.save(validate: false)
  end
end
```

Despite my document.save(validate: false), the process loop during the updating.
I tried after_update callback, tweak my code and conditions, with no success.
Thank you in advance for your precious help

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but happened to me today and solved this way....a bit hacky btw... I'm not proud of my solution. This works in Rails 5.

1. Added a virtual attribute to my model "skip_callbacks"
2. Added a method to check if the attribute is true "should_skip_callbacks?"
3. In my callback added "unless: :should_skip_callbacks?" condition
4. Before the paperclip reprocess, set the virtual attribute "skip_callbacks" to true

Here's a simplified version of my model:

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord 

  attr_accessor :skip_callbacks
  has_attached_file :logo, styles: { header: "380x160>" }
  validates_attachment :logo, content_type: {content_type: ['image/png','image/jpg','image/gif']}

  after_save :reprocess_logo, unless: :should_skip_callbacks?

  def should_skip_callbacks?
    self.skip_callbacks
  end   

  def reprocess_logo
    self.skip_callbacks = true
    self.logo.reprocess!
  end   


end
```